# Show that sequence converges of $r_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

We have the function $f(x)=x^2-x-12=0$ with roots $r_1=-3$ and $r_2=4$.

We consider the sequence $x_{n+1}=g(x_n), \ n=0,1,2,\ldots $ where $g(x)=\sqrt{x+12}$.

We want to show that $x_n\rightarrow r_2, \ \forall x_0\in [-3,12]$.

Let $x_n\rightarrow c$ then $x_{n+1}\rightarrow c$. We have that $c=g(c)$ and $c$ must be a root of $f$, which is either $-3$ or $4$.

Is my idea correct? Or do we show in an other way that $x_n\rightarrow r_2$ ?

Comment: That's correct, but only part of the solution. First you have to show that the sequence converges at all. You also have to exclude the possibility that $c=-3$.

Comment: How do we show that the sequence converges? Could you give me a hint? @MartinR

Comment: A common technique in this context is to show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded.

Comment: First thing I did as a 'warm-up', was to calculate the sequences when $x_0 = -3$ and  $x_0 =12$. Got a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, but incomplete.

- First you have to show that the sequence converges at all. *Hint:* Show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded. Distinguish the cases $x_0 < 4$ and $x_0 > 4$.
- Then you are correct: If the sequence is convergent then the limit is either $-3$ or $4$. But you have to exclude the possibility that $c=-3$. *Hint:* $x_n \ge 0$ for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: At the second part, do we just say that since $x_n\geq 0$ for $n\geq 1$ then $c$ must be $4$,  no matter what $x_0$ is?

Comment: Yes. $x_n \ge 0$ implies $c = \lim x_n \ge 0$, that excludes $c=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

The OP might need to know the following:

Proposition 1: Let $(u_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a convergent sequence and set $v_k = u_{k+1}$. Then

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} v_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n$$

Proposition 2: Let $(u_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(v_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be two sequences that converge to the same limit $L$. Then

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n^2  = \lim_{n\to \infty} v_n^2 = L^2$$

Comment: What does the limit of a sum have to do with it?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I meant  $\lim_{n\to \infty}( u_n + c) = [\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n] + c$, but that is really getting silly (changed my answer).